# passing bokeh.document.to_json_string() output to bokehJS

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I would like to pass the output of the `bokeh.document.to_json_string()`function as input to the bokehJS library to instantiate a bokeh graph standalone without a bokeh-server.

I would like to not have to save the graph in bokeh as html.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure that you have read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The standard way of embedding Bokeh models from standalone documents into your own custom templates is to use [`bokeh.embed.components`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) (link goes to version `0.11.1` docs) Is there some reason this would not work for you, if so can you explain what is different about your circumstance?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I will look into this.
I wanted to store the json with a database and reload them later. I can also add the generated scripts and div the db, but having only a json object sounded promising